# word for a condescending, snarky, yet awkward and jealous, person

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, slang

i'm looking for a word for a person who is cynical, judgmental, nitpicking, condescending but also flawed, gawky and timid (in an unfamiliar setting), and is harboring some kind of jealousy towards other people, especially those whom he/she hates.

An example of this kind of person is Lizzy Caplan's Janis in *Mean Girls*. you know the girl who first befriended Lindsay Lohan's character and convinced her to get along with the the plastics in order to exact revenge on Regina george?

Also, the word (or words) could be formal or slang.

Comment: "Queen Bitch" comes to mind. :P

Comment: I don't know if it's *too* simple, but possibly just 'insecure'?

Comment: I'd say "arsehole".  Joking aside, what is the point of saying "Is there an adjective which can be used instead of these five adjectives which all have different meanings?"  Are you trying to insult someone as tersely as possible?  Are you paying by the word?

Comment: I wonder what a version would be like if it was written by a person who was more like Regina George. Would it be a bad story, or would it show an entirely different world? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

*Insecure* is quite a good word. Insecure people will be

> flawed, gawky and timid (in an unfamiliar setting)
> and often times jealousy accompanies insecurity hand in hand.

As far as

> cynical, judgmental, nitpicking, condescending

goes,

> petulant : (of a person or their manner) childishly sulky or bad-tempered.

comes to mind.

Others include

> supercilious : having or showing the proud and unpleasant attitude of people who think that they are better or more important than other people
>
> haughty: : having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people

and of course *pretentious*

Comment: I like this answer because it some way it seems to evoke two sets of faults, the one resonating with the other. I can sort of see a play in my head acted out as I read it.

Answer (score 0):

**Patronizing** could work

(As defined on dictionary.com)

> [Patronizing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patronizing) - displaying or indicative of an offensively condescending manner